# Simple JNDI ContextFactory?

Tags: java, jndi

My WAR application is deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. They don't support JNDI, but I need it for JPA and unit tests. What JNDI context factory I can use as a workaround? I need a simple open source solution, that would allow me to configure entire factory through `jndi.properties`. I tried GuiceyFruit, but looks like it doesn't allow data source configuration inside one file. Any suggestions?

ps. OpenEJB will work, but it's an overkill for such a simple task

Comment: It looks very closer to the solution outlined in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521421/how-do-i-lookup-a-jndi-datasource-from-outside-a-web-container

Comment: Could you explain why u need JNDI for JPA and unit tests ?

Comment: www.briskbee.com/2010/07/setting-up-datasource-in-jndi.html

Answer (score 3):

Try Simple-JNDI. It gives you an in-memory implementation of a JNDI Service and allows you to populate the JNDI environment with objects defined in property files. There is also support for loading datasources or connection pools configured in a file.

To get a connection pool you have to create a file like this:

```
type=javax.sql.DataSource
driver=com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
pool=myDataSource
url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:servername:5000
user=user
password=password
```

In your application you can access the pool via

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("path/to/your/connectionPool");
```

You can find more about it at https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI.